# Eureka RestTemplate and SSL

Tags: java, ssl, resttemplate, netflix-eureka

I've configured my eureka client and service to use SSL with self-signed certs. Created the keystores and imported the certs from client into server keystore and vice-a-versa. however now when I attempt to use the restTemplate

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

which used to resolve my service http://my-service/convert/ without any bothers using the underlying framework it can no longer do this? The HTTP response is 302 with secure:/ HTTPOnly

I attempted to configure the restTemplate a little more manually as such

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .create()
            .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:client.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray(), allPassword.toCharArray())
            .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:client.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray())
            .build();

    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

and while the restTemplate is creating okay it now appears not to know about my-service from the Eureka framework?

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: my-service
```

has anyone configured a eureka client/service for SSL and also a load-balanced restTemplate that can consume a rest service from the client's jvm?

I was using the article from the excellent baeldung guy's website
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

however it doesn't appear to apply to restTemplate's provided by the eureka framework.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: You say it works when you're not using `SSL`, but the specific error message you get means that the `hostname` `my-service` is not known (ie. it cannot be resolved to an IP). Direct quote from the [UnknownHostException Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined."

Comment: Yes the eureka framework resolves the service name my-service when you autowire the bean in the class as just a member variable but when I do that the call from the template returns a 320 status code saying it should be redirecting and the body is empty.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you now connecting to [https://my-service/convert/](https://my-service/convert/) if not I would try that? If you connect using HTTPS I wouldn't expect a redirect based on the change to SSL. Also I would expect a `302 Found` to also contain a `Location` header, are you seeing that? A `302` doesn't necessarily contain a body as it expects the client to resend the request to the new `Location`

Comment: Hi Misantorp, thanks for getting back to me. Yes the url I'm using is https://my-service/convert/ and you're dead right! Thanks very much. The redirect has a location with a link to the login on the actual machine i.e. https://my-machine.mycompany.com:8082/login. I'm not sure why it's doing that though as I haven't configured any spring security to say it should redirect? It's doing so automatically. But that is progress thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Misantorp for pointing out that the service was trying to redirect to the /login context. It appears just configuring the spring boot app for HTTPs was enough to trigger some Spring security. Thought that was a little strange as I had none in there previously.

I initiated some spring security, permittedAll("/**") and disable csrf and the client successfully calls there server again.